# Check if the characters of the scrambled String match the second String

Tags: java

The method `stringScramble()` accepts two `Strings` one of which represents a `scrambled String`(such as `rkqodlw`) and the second one represents an actual word (such as `world`) and returns `true` if the `scrambled String` can be rearranged to match the second `String`
For example, when I type:

```
Enter two Strings: 
ellho
hello
false
```

then the program is giving me `false` instead of `true` as `ellho` can be rearranged as `hello`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringScamble {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two Strings: ");
        String myString1 = kbd.nextLine();
        String myString2 = kbd.nextLine();

        boolean result = stringScramble(myString1, myString2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static boolean stringScramble(String myString1, String myString2)
    {
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < myString1.length(); i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < myString2.length(); j++)
            {
                if(myString1.charAt(i) == myString2.charAt(j))
                    temp += myString1.charAt(i);
            }
        if(temp.equals(myString1))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A simpler solution may be to count the number of each character in each string and compare the results. Also, it is unclear to me whether extra characters can be in the scrambled string or not.

Comment: @clcto, I'm doing the exercises from Coderbyte.com and the `scrambled String` includes extra characters according to the exercise.

Comment: Nevermind, folks! I traced everything and my problem was in the nested for-loops. Basically, I just swtiched the `myString1` with `myString2` and added the `break` statement inside the if-statement. Everything is working right now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop checks if character `i` of the first string is equal to character `j` of the second, and if so appends it to the `temp` string. This should work ok for strings with unique characters, but if you compare `ellho` to `hello`, you'll hit four cases where the `l`s are equal, which is not the intended behavior.

Since the order doesn't matter in your comparison, you could just count the number of times each character appears in each string and compare them.
E.g.:

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> charCount (String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        Integer cnt = result.get(c);
        if (cnt == null) {
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt = cnt + 1;
        }
        result.put (c, cnt);
    }
    return result; 
}

public static boolean stringScramble(String myString1, String myString2)
    return charCount(myString1).equals(charCount(myString2));
}
```